# why Scalffold is not filling bottom of the screen in android?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, scaffold

I am new to Flutter. My screen don't have anything else - only a scaffold. I don't know why, it is not filling the entire screen.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,

          
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, add the current code you are running. Here is [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added the code. But that code was already in flutter, I just added a background color to scaffold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the bottom area is a part of the Android navigation bar, hence you need to change the background of it explicitly:

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.green),
  );

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    ),
  );
}
```

For more information, check the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiOverlayStyle-class.html).

Comment: Thankyou. Is there any way to make it transparent? When I try to make it transparent with colors.transparent it return a white background. I want my background image to fill the entire screen

Comment: Not sure, but you should play a little with the properties of the [Scaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) widget, like `extendBody` or `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`. Also, do not reject the option of not using Scaffold and just simply put your image as a background of Container or any similar widget.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the SafeArea Widget, it's used to cover the top and bottom of the screen or not :
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html

The bottom is what you care :

```
SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(),
  bottom: false/true,
)
```

It's aware of the current context MediaQuery and the View Padding

Comment: It's still not working. Is there any other way. Don't tell me I have to quit flutter before started